# Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: null - after validation in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

```
Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: null
```

This is error which I am getting when I try to validate my archive in Xcode. I can't find anything about this in internet and I some days ago just updated my app in AppStore.

Any idea what is the problem in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue because of my mac storage is full. Once i free up storage of my mac Device my archive file successfully validates.